# How to load a single webpage in a windows application?

Tags: vb.net, windows, webview

```
Private Sub 

    WebView_LoadCompleted()
    webView1.NavigateToLocalStreamUri(google.com)

End Sub
```

I would simply like to create an app that displays google.com in the webview. However I get errors, and it doesn't work. Is there an easy way to display a single webpage in webview for windows?

Answer (score 0):

you could try this....

private sub

Dim uri As New Uri("http://www.google.com")

webView1.Navigate(targetUri)

end sub